# simplified expression for ${}_1F_1(1,s+1,z)$ for $s$ positive integer.

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I know and can show that

\begin{equation*}
  {}_{1}F_{1}\left(1,s,z\right)=1+\frac{z}s\,{}_{1}F_{1}\left(1,s+1,z\right)
\end{equation*}

From here, I get:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
{}_{1}F_{1}\left(1,s+1,z\right)&= \frac sz\left\{{}_{1}F_{1}\left(1,s,z\right)-1\right\} \\
& = \frac sz\left[\frac {s-1}z\left\{{}_{1}F_{1}\left(1,s-1,z\right)-1\right\}-1\right]\\
& = \frac{s!}{z^s}\exp{(z)} - \sum_{l=0}^{s-1} \frac{s!}{z^{s-l}l!}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

From the suggested reference to [Eq. (8.5.1)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.5#E1), this means that for integers,

\begin{equation*} 
\gamma(s,z) = =\frac{s!}{z^s}\left(1-\exp{(-z)}\sum_{l=0}^{s-1}\frac{z^l}{l!} \right)   = \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{z^s}\left(1-\exp{(-z)}\sum_{l=0}^{s-1}\frac{z^l}{\Gamma(l+1)} \right) 
\end{equation*}

My question is, does the right hand side also hold for non-integer $s$, but more importantly if there is further simplification possible for the expression of ${}_{1}F_{1}\left(1,s+1,z\right)$, or if there is some other easier representation fot this special case?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: The correct result is $$
{}_1F_1 (1,s + 1,z) = \frac{{s!}}{{z^s }}\left( {{\rm e}^z  - \sum\limits_{\ell  = 0}^{s - 1} {\frac{{z^\ell  }}{{\ell !}}} } \right)
$$ for $s=0,1,2,\ldots$. See also [$(8.5.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.5.E1).

Comment: Thanks for the correction, now corrected.

Comment: [Mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOF9B.png) says $\operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( 1;\, s + 1;\, z \right) = e^{z} \cdot s \cdot z^{-s} \cdot \left( \Gamma\left( s \right) - \Gamma\left( s,\, x \right) \right)$. You can simplify your last step using [formula $2$ from here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html). You would get: $\sum_{l=0}^{s-1} \frac{s!}{z^{s-l}l!} = \frac{s!}{z^{s}}\sum_{l=0}^{s-1} \frac{z^{l}}{l!} = \frac{s!}{z^{s}} \frac{e^x}{(s-1)!}\Gamma(s,\,x) = s e^x z^{-s} \Gamma(s,\,x)$.

Comment: Thank you @KevinDietrich, so does that mean that the formula holds for non-integers s too, with the factorial defined appropriately?

Comment: @user3236841 The first formula from [mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnB2K.png) is true for all $s \in \mathbb{C} \wedge \Re\left( s \right) \ne 0$ (with $z = x$ - i did a typo there). The second formula is only true for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (because an upper limit (of the sum) that is no integer makes no sense).

Comment: yes, of course, thank you! how does one prove this?